# Friends and Friendlists in Facebook

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

How do I find out if a friend is in for example the aquaintances or good friends or another custom  friend_list with the JS SDK. Im working with a singlepage javascript application in phonegap.

The main issue is that I need different sets of data, that aren't useable outside of the callback function.

I tried to query all my friend lists like so,

```
FB.api('me/friendlists'){
});
```

And all my friends like so

```
 FB.api('me/friends', function(friends){
 friends.data.forEach(function(friend){
 });
 });
```

but they both use callback functions, i need to compare the 2 results and add a property listname and/or id to the friends result.

Comment: Hi! this is not a way of asking any question.we are not getting what ur query is.just edit ur question and describe each and every step in detail and tell us what u have tried than we will try to guide u.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `read_friendlists` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) you can access a user's friends lists.

Then, make a call to `/[USER_ID]/friendlists` to get the friend list List ids, then a call to `/[FRIEND LIST ID]` to get the list of friends on that list.

You can then store those and check if a specific uid is on one of the lists

Comment: The problem here is I can't store data :( not in localstorage anyway.

Comment: So don't store it; retrieve it from the API and use it in the app