# Facebook Friends in each Friendlist

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get a list of friends along with their friend_list_type?

I tried to get all the list_types by making the following call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]/friendlists?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

On receiving this, I tried ti iterate over the list_types and make the following call to get the list of friends on each list_type:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[FRIEND_LIST_ID]/members?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

But, I always get an empty array in response, like this:

```
{
 "data": [

 ]
}
```

I am sure that the user is having friends mapped to multiple friend_list_types. But, still I am getting NO result. Is there anything which I am not aware of? 
Note that, I tried this on all versions of Facebook Graph API and I also have read_friendlists permission to access the user's friend_list.

Answer (score 1):

The friendlists endpoint is only a list of the friendlists, there is no way to get the friends in those friendlists.

Think of it this way: What if someone creates a list called "Idjits" and puts some friends in it. No App should be allowed to read that kind of information ;)

Comment: I am not really convinced that it is not possible. Seems that it was possible with version 1.0. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187988/friends-and-friendlists-in-facebook and also this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/friendlist/members.

Comment: it´s not possible in v2.x, and v1.0 does not really matter anymore. no need to add that information to the answer imho, it does not work in new apps anymore and it will stop working for all apps after april 2015.